# WPF Built-in Commands

Tags: .net, wpf, command

I'm looking for a complete list of built-in WPF Commands.

The best list I've found so far is [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Concepts%E2%80%94Built-In_Commands), but it does not list all commands.

Some nice-to-have details would be:

- Controls/components with support to the commands (for example, [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx) supports edit commands such as Paste, Copy, Cut, Redo, and Undo);
- Default Key Gestures and UI Text (can be extracted from [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.help.aspx)).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

It is easy to display a complete list of all commands in all loaded assemblies:

```
  public string[] GetAllCommands()
  {
    return (
      from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
      from type in assembly.GetTypes()
      from prop in type.GetProperties()
      where
        typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType) &&
        prop.GetAccessors()[0].IsStatic
      orderby type.Name, prop.Name
      select type.Name + "." + prop.Name
    ).ToArray();
  }
```

With PresentationFramework loaded I get the list at the bottom of this answer, which you will see is absolutely complete.

If you also want to see the command type (eg RoutedUIComand) and gestures, you can add this to the LINQ:

```
      let commandType = prop.PropertyType

      let gestures =
        typeof(UIElement).IsAssignableFrom(commandType) ?
          ((UIElement)prop.GetValue(null)).InputGestures :
        null
```

Then your select might be something like this:

```
      select type.Name + "." + prop.Name + " " + commandType.Name + " " + gestures
```

Programmatically finding out which controls do something with a given command is also possible.  Basically something like this ought to work (not tried, but this will give you the idea):

```
var allCommands = (
  from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
  from type in assembly.GetTypes()
  from prop in type.GetProperties()
  where
    typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType) &&
    prop.GetAccessors()[0].IsStatic
  orderby type.Name, prop.Name
  select new
  {
    typeName = type.Name,
    propName = prop.Name,
    displayAs = type.Name + "." + prop.Name,
  }
).ToArray();

var classesReferencingCommand = (
  from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
  from type in assembly.GetTypes()
  from method in type.GetMethods()
  let methodBodyString = ConvertILToString(method.MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray())
  let info = new
  {
    typeName = type.FullName,
    referencedCommands =
      from cmd in allCommands
      where
        methodBodyString.Contains(cmd.typeName) &&
        methodBodyString.Contains(cmd.propName)
      select cmd
  }
  where info.commands.Any()
  select info
).ToArray();
```

where ConvertILToString would probably be something like this:

```
static string ConvertILToString(byte[] bytes)
{
  return new string(bytes.Where(b => b!=0).Select(b => (char)b).ToArray());
}
```

The results can be used any way you like, for example they can be displayed using an ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl Source="{Binding classesReferencingCommand}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding typeName}" FontWeight="Bold">
        <ItemsControl Source="{Binding referencedCommands}" Margin="10 0 0 0">
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding displayAs}" />
      ... close all tags ...
```

Alternatively you could output the data in a text or XML format or add it to a database.  Also note that this second query can be turned around with the command iteration on the outside if you prefer a listing by command.

The code above will give you the precise facts and will not lie, because it is looking at the NET Framework itself.

Here is the promised list of all commands in PresentationFramework:

```
ApplicationCommands.CancelPrint
ApplicationCommands.Close
ApplicationCommands.ContextMenu
ApplicationCommands.Copy
ApplicationCommands.CorrectionList
ApplicationCommands.Cut
ApplicationCommands.Delete
ApplicationCommands.Find
ApplicationCommands.Help
ApplicationCommands.New
ApplicationCommands.NotACommand
ApplicationCommands.Open
ApplicationCommands.Paste
ApplicationCommands.Print
ApplicationCommands.PrintPreview
ApplicationCommands.Properties
ApplicationCommands.Redo
ApplicationCommands.Replace
ApplicationCommands.Save
ApplicationCommands.SaveAs
ApplicationCommands.SelectAll
ApplicationCommands.Stop
ApplicationCommands.Undo
ComponentCommands.ExtendSelectionDown
ComponentCommands.ExtendSelectionLeft
ComponentCommands.ExtendSelectionRight
ComponentCommands.ExtendSelectionUp
ComponentCommands.MoveDown
ComponentCommands.MoveFocusBack
ComponentCommands.MoveFocusDown
ComponentCommands.MoveFocusForward
ComponentCommands.MoveFocusPageDown
ComponentCommands.MoveFocusPageUp
ComponentCommands.MoveFocusUp
ComponentCommands.MoveLeft
ComponentCommands.MoveRight
ComponentCommands.MoveToEnd
ComponentCommands.MoveToHome
ComponentCommands.MoveToPageDown
ComponentCommands.MoveToPageUp
ComponentCommands.MoveUp
ComponentCommands.ScrollByLine
ComponentCommands.ScrollPageDown
ComponentCommands.ScrollPageLeft
ComponentCommands.ScrollPageRight
ComponentCommands.ScrollPageUp
ComponentCommands.SelectToEnd
ComponentCommands.SelectToHome
ComponentCommands.SelectToPageDown
ComponentCommands.SelectToPageUp
DocumentViewer.FitToHeightCommand
DocumentViewer.FitToMaxPagesAcrossCommand
DocumentViewer.FitToWidthCommand
DocumentViewer.ViewThumbnailsCommand
EditingCommands.AlignCenter
EditingCommands.AlignJustify
EditingCommands.AlignLeft
EditingCommands.AlignRight
EditingCommands.Backspace
EditingCommands.CorrectSpellingError
EditingCommands.DecreaseFontSize
EditingCommands.DecreaseIndentation
EditingCommands.Delete
EditingCommands.DeleteNextWord
EditingCommands.DeletePreviousWord
EditingCommands.EnterLineBreak
EditingCommands.EnterParagraphBreak
EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError
EditingCommands.IncreaseFontSize
EditingCommands.IncreaseIndentation
EditingCommands.MoveDownByLine
EditingCommands.MoveDownByPage
EditingCommands.MoveDownByParagraph
EditingCommands.MoveLeftByCharacter
EditingCommands.MoveLeftByWord
EditingCommands.MoveRightByCharacter
EditingCommands.MoveRightByWord
EditingCommands.MoveToDocumentEnd
EditingCommands.MoveToDocumentStart
EditingCommands.MoveToLineEnd
EditingCommands.MoveToLineStart
EditingCommands.MoveUpByLine
EditingCommands.MoveUpByPage
EditingCommands.MoveUpByParagraph
EditingCommands.SelectDownByLine
EditingCommands.SelectDownByPage
EditingCommands.SelectDownByParagraph
EditingCommands.SelectLeftByCharacter
EditingCommands.SelectLeftByWord
EditingCommands.SelectRightByCharacter
EditingCommands.SelectRightByWord
EditingCommands.SelectToDocumentEnd
EditingCommands.SelectToDocumentStart
EditingCommands.SelectToLineEnd
EditingCommands.SelectToLineStart
EditingCommands.SelectUpByLine
EditingCommands.SelectUpByPage
EditingCommands.SelectUpByParagraph
EditingCommands.TabBackward
EditingCommands.TabForward
EditingCommands.ToggleBold
EditingCommands.ToggleBullets
EditingCommands.ToggleInsert
EditingCommands.ToggleItalic
EditingCommands.ToggleNumbering
EditingCommands.ToggleSubscript
EditingCommands.ToggleSuperscript
EditingCommands.ToggleUnderline
MediaCommands.BoostBass
MediaCommands.ChannelDown
MediaCommands.ChannelUp
MediaCommands.DecreaseBass
MediaCommands.DecreaseMicrophoneVolume
MediaCommands.DecreaseTreble
MediaCommands.DecreaseVolume
MediaCommands.FastForward
MediaCommands.IncreaseBass
MediaCommands.IncreaseMicrophoneVolume
MediaCommands.IncreaseTreble
MediaCommands.IncreaseVolume
MediaCommands.MuteMicrophoneVolume
MediaCommands.MuteVolume
MediaCommands.NextTrack
MediaCommands.Pause
MediaCommands.Play
MediaCommands.PreviousTrack
MediaCommands.Record
MediaCommands.Rewind
MediaCommands.Select
MediaCommands.Stop
MediaCommands.ToggleMicrophoneOnOff
MediaCommands.TogglePlayPause
NavigationCommands.BrowseBack
NavigationCommands.BrowseForward
NavigationCommands.BrowseHome
NavigationCommands.BrowseStop
NavigationCommands.DecreaseZoom
NavigationCommands.Favorites
NavigationCommands.FirstPage
NavigationCommands.GoToPage
NavigationCommands.IncreaseZoom
NavigationCommands.LastPage
NavigationCommands.NavigateJournal
NavigationCommands.NextPage
NavigationCommands.PreviousPage
NavigationCommands.Refresh
NavigationCommands.Search
NavigationCommands.Zoom
Slider.DecreaseLarge
Slider.DecreaseSmall
Slider.IncreaseLarge
Slider.IncreaseSmall
Slider.MaximizeValue
Slider.MinimizeValue
```

This list is complete.

If there are any additional gestures in the themes, they can easily be extracted by loading the theme resource dictionary and doing some LINQ on it.  The queries are trivial:  Just search for `<InputGesture>`.   **Update:** I don't think there are any gestures in the themes, since the default gestures are loaded from resources.  So this part will probably not be necessary.

Comment: man, I think this is the best answer so far. I'll try the *classesReferencingCommand* query this weekend. For a while, I'll keep the question open to see if anything else comes on, but I guess you'll have the accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Check out the [ApplicationCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx), [ComponentCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.componentcommands.aspx) and [NavigationCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.navigationcommands.aspx) classes. These classes all contain static properties representing various, standard routed commands which you can use within your own applications and to interact with intrinsic controls within the framework.

Comment: I already looked at them, but the information I'm looking for is too spread-out. I'm looking for a compact list with all the commands, and some few relevant notes.

Comment: You're trying to build more of a compendium of commands, I understand. I will edit if I have some time. Microsoft should really have a standard section in the MSDN documentation for WPF controls called "Supported Commands" or something like that.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Initially, I thought MSDN already had such documentation. And that's why I flagged the question as community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this link http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Concepts%E2%80%94Built-In_Commands

WPF's built-in commands are exposed as static properties of five different classes:

```
    * ApplicationCommands—Close, Copy, Cut, Delete, Find, Help, New, Open, Paste, Print, PrintPreview, Properties, Redo, Replace, Save, SaveAs, SelectAll, Stop, Undo, and more 

    * ComponentCommands—MoveDown, MoveLeft, MoveRight, MoveUp, ScrollByLine, ScrollPageDown, ScrollPageLeft, ScrollPageRight, ScrollPageUp, SelectToEnd, SelectToHome, SelectToPageDown, SelectToPageUp, and more 

    * MediaCommands—ChannelDown, ChannelUp, DecreaseVolume, FastForward, IncreaseVolume, MuteVolume, NextTrack, Pause, Play, PreviousTrack, Record, Rewind, Select, Stop, and more 

    * NavigationCommands—BrowseBack, BrowseForward, BrowseHome, BrowseStop, Favorites, FirstPage, GoToPage, LastPage, NextPage, PreviousPage, Refresh, Search, Zoom, and more 

    * EditingCommands—AlignCenter, AlignJustify, AlignLeft, AlignRight, CorrectSpellingError, DecreaseFontSize, DecreaseIndentation, EnterLineBreak, EnterParagraphBreak, IgnoreSpellingError, IncreaseFontSize, IncreaseIndentation, MoveDownByLine, MoveDownByPage, MoveDownByParagraph, MoveLeftByCharacter, MoveLeftByWord, MoveRightByCharacter, MoveRightByWord, and more
```

Comment: That's the same link that I've put on the question. Thanks for replying anyway.